# WordPress POST action is null

Tags: wordpress, forms, get

I'm trying to make a simple login form for my WordPress theme. I thought I followed WP documentation correctly, but I'm seeing that my forms action is not being detected.

I can see in my error log 'got here 1' is printing. Looking at process_form.php below, this condition should indicate that my user is not logged in and that action is empty.

I believed that this line from my form processing code:

```
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_streamLogForm', 'showroom_login_user' );
```

and this line from my actual form

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="streamLogForm">
```

would interact to bind the form action to this admin_post hook.

The showroom_login_user() function works and my GET variables actually seem to be working (at first I thought they were not), but still not sure why I'm reaching this condition.

### login.php

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">     
        function validateLoginForm() {
                
            var email = document.forms["streamLogForm"]["user_email"].value;
            var password = document.forms["streamLogForm"]["user_password"].value;
    
            if ( email == null || email == "" ) { 
                alert("User must be entered"); 
                return false; 
            } else if ( password == null || password == "" ) {
                alert("Password must be entered"); 
                return false; 
            }
               
            return true;
            
        }
    
    </script>   
</head>

<div class="">

    <form name="streamLogForm"  id="streamLoginForm" onsubmit="return validateLoginForm()" action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>" method="get" >
    
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="streamLogForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="location" value="<?php echo $URI ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="action_type" value="<?php echo 'login'?>" />

        <div class="field">
            <label for="streamUserEmail">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" id="streamUserEmail" name="user_email">
        </div>
        
        <div class="field">
            <label for="streamUserPassword">Password: </label>
            <input type="password" id="streamUserEmail" name="user_password">
        </div>
       
        <button> Login </button>
        
    </form>
    
</div>
```

### process_form.php

```
<?php

if ( ! wp_validate_auth_cookie() ) {
    if ( empty( $action ) ) { 
        error_log('got here 1', 0);  
        do_action( 'admin_post_nopriv' );
    } else { 
        error_log('got here 2', 0);
        do_action( "admin_post_nopriv_{$action}" );
    }
} else {
    if ( empty( $action ) ){ 
        error_log('got here 3', 0); 
        do_action( 'admin_post' ); 
    } else { 
        error_log('got here 4', 0); 
        do_action( "admin_post_{$action}" );
    }
}

function showroom_login_user() 
{
    error_log("GOT HERE 6!", 0);

    $location = $_GET["action_type"];
    $action_type = $_GET["action_type"];
    $user_email = $_GET["user_email"];
    $user_password = $_GET["user_password"];

    echo 'testing......' . $user_email;
}
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_streamLogForm', 'showroom_login_user' );
add_action( 'admin_post_streamLogForm', 'showroom_login_user' );

?>
```

Comment: Why not use `admin_url('admin-ajax.php');` action instead `admin_url('admin-post.php')` .?

Comment: A lot of things on the site are using Ajax, wasn't sure if it was necessary here. Started to feel like I was over doing it with ajax calls.

though it probably would be better here since I will have to do header re-directs to the page the user clicked from.

Comment: `admin_url('admin-ajax.php');` that doesn't mean you are doing it via Ajax, HTML form also can be submitted via that `action`. I will post an answer using that.

Answer (score 2):

Update your form tag like this

```
<form name="streamLogForm"  id="streamLoginForm" onsubmit="return validateLoginForm()" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>" method="get" >
```

and place this snippet on your `functions.php`

```
function showroom_login_user() {

    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = $_GET["user_email"];
    $creds['user_password'] = $_GET["user_password"];
    $creds['remember'] = true;

    $autologin_user = wp_signon( $creds, false );

    if ( !is_wp_error($autologin_user) ) {
        // "Logged In.!";
    } else {
        // "Log In Failed.!";
    }
    // do your redirect here
    wp_safe_redirect( "URL of the page to be redirected" );

}

add_action ( 'wp_ajax_quick_streamLogForm', 'showroom_login_user' );
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_streamLogForm', 'showroom_login_user' );
```

Comment: Looks useful. I will test this out a little later tonight : >